Understand lsof outputs for remote port forwarding SSH connections
Given ServerB and ServerA, I run the following command on ServerB to setup Remote Port Forwarding, so that requests arriving on port 4000 on serverA are forwarding to ServerB:22.
ssh -R 4000:localhost:22 user@serverA
On my local machine, I can now connect to ServerB by jump on ServerA port 4000.
ssh -J user@serverA user@localhost -p 4000 
This works.
I am trying to understand why the output from the following command (when run on ServerA)
sudo lsof -i -P -n
Does not demonstrate my expectation.
Instead of seeing an output like...
...
sshd   TCP 127.0.0.1:4000->serverB:22 (ESTABLISHED)
...

I see these instead...
...
sshd     TCP [::1]:4000 (LISTEN)
sshd     TCP 127.0.0.1:4000 (LISTEN)
sshd     TCP 127.0.0.1:4000->127.0.0.1:4340 (ESTABLISHED)
...

These do not mention ServerB, and particuarly the last row just suggests a local connection to another random port.
Why is this, and given the scenario described above, how can I output a meaningful description of it?

In your ssh commands you don't use serverB anywhere, only localhost and ServerA, based on that it is obvious you won't connect to serverB

localhost in the first SSH command is referring to ServerB (the command is run on ServerB)

ssh -R 4000:localhost:22 user@serverA

tells ServerA to locally listen on port 4000. Any connection made to this port on ServerA is forwarded to ServerB on port 22. However, ServerA itself manages the forwarding locally though, which is why lsof only shows connections like seen above. You may want to check SSH logs on ServerA, or use netstat to get the connections from ServerA to ServerB.
